# "Never did I think" vs. "Never had I thought"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I learnt at school that *had P.P.* means something happened before a certain event.

ex) I had eaten all the cake when John arrived.

Then, what is the difference between the following two sentences?

A) Never did I think Mary would come.

B) Never had I thought Mary would come.

I don't catch the difference.  Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Assuming that both imply that Mary did in fact come, B emphasises the fact that _before_ she arrived you had never expected her.

Comment: Are they basically the same?

Comment: What I said in my previous comment. If Mary did come, they mean the same with the slight difference I explained.